# Must be list or null Exception when attempting to pandas json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a pandas dataframe containing `json` data that I am attempting to normalize using pandas `json_normalize`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1],
                   'j': [{'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g':[]}}, {'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g':[]}}]
                 })

dff = pd.json_normalize(df['j'], record_path=['loc'], meta=['id'])
dff


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-3958878855945685>:6
      1 df = pd.DataFrame({
      2                    'id': [0, 1],
      3                    'j': [{'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g':[]}}, {'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g':[]}}]
      4                  })
----> 6 dff = pd.json_normalize(df['j'], record_path=['loc'], meta=['id'])
      7 dff

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py:515, in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    512                 meta_vals[key].append(meta_val)
    513             records.extend(recs)
--> 515 _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
    517 result = DataFrame(records)
    519 if record_prefix is not None:
    520     # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[DataFrame]",
    521     # variable has type "DataFrame")

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py:497, in _json_normalize.<locals>._recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level)
    495 else:
    496     for obj in data:
--> 497         recs = _pull_records(obj, path[0])
    498         recs = [
    499             nested_to_record(r, sep=sep, max_level=max_level)
    500             if isinstance(r, dict)
    501             else r
    502             for r in recs
    503         ]
    505         # For repeating the metadata later

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py:427, in _json_normalize.<locals>._pull_records(js, spec)
    425         result = []
    426     else:
--> 427         raise TypeError(
    428             f"{js} has non list value {result} for path {spec}. "
    429             "Must be list or null."
    430         )
    431 return result

TypeError: {'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': []}} has non list value {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': []} for path loc. Must be list or null.
```

Also, there might be some json data where the string would be an empty string. How would I handle that exception? Desired behavior is if the `key` is not found, there normalize with `np.nan`.

Expected output:

```
s.value s.text ps.value ps.text  g.value g.text   g.id  id
0      0.0    xxx      0.0    xxx      2.0    xxx  [0.0]   0
1      0.0    xxx      0.0    xxx      2.0    xxx  [0.0]   1
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @mozway update the post with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You json is invalid, you should have a list in `loc` and you als have a duplicated `g` key. Also you can't use `id` as meta as this key doesn't exist in the json.

With a correct format, this should give:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1],
                   'j': [{'type': 's', 'loc': [{'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}}]},
                         {'type': 's', 'loc': [{'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}}]}
                        ]
                 })

dff = pd.json_normalize(df['j'], record_path=['loc'])
```

Output:

```
  s.value s.text ps.value ps.text g.value g.text
0     0.0    xxx      0.0     xxx     2.0    xxx
1     0.0    xxx      0.0     xxx     2.0    xxx
```

With your current format, assuming no duplication of `g` you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1],
                   'j': [{'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}}},
                         {'type': 's', 'loc': {'s': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'ps': {'value': '0.0', 'text': 'xxx'}, 'g': {'value': '2.0', 'text': 'xxx'}}}]
                 })

pd.json_normalize(df['j'].str['loc'])
```

Output:

```
  s.value s.text ps.value ps.text g.value g.text
0     0.0    xxx      0.0     xxx     2.0    xxx
1     0.0    xxx      0.0     xxx     2.0    xxx
```